# Timer-triggered Azure Function not triggered on scheduled time and failed with Azure storage timeout exception

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-storage-emulator

I have a V-1 time triggered Azure Function created from VS used to get data back from a service with estimated time 9 mins via HTTPCLIENT, it runs well locally, and using storage emulator.  But when I published to Azure portal with App Service Plan, two problems arise: 1> Monitor tab not showing all executions, as there are more failed executions I can find if I go to Application Insights, plus the triggered time in Application Insights are not the scheduled time frequency(every 6 hrs I set)   2> Most of them failed with below snapshot.
[System.TimeoutException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22Wn4.png)

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: you should really upgrade to v2, you will save yourself a lot of time with troubleshooting

Comment: Documentation suggest create a new function app runs on v2, and port the existing code to there. Yet that require grant access to this new app from different services, since my function now talks to many other services. Or is there a well documented guide you could share about upgrading the existing function to v2? Thanks

Comment: you can set up a proxy from the v1 to go to the v2 while you update the services to point to v2

Answer (score 0):

There is a suggestion in one of the Github issues, and the solution was to disable dashboard logging in the code using the following snippet:

```
 var config = new JobHostConfiguration();
        config.DashboardConnectionString = null;
```

The full post can be viewed [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1393)

Comment: Tired that, not working...plus the Azure Function seems not being triggered, no execution record from both monitor tab and Application Insights...

Comment: As discussed at [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/394ef8a7-3f17-47c5-8443-17723c9a856e/invocation-logs-not-updating-in-portal?forum=AzureFunctions), functions actually being invoked, but not logged in Azure Portal, when I go to https://<<functionappname>>.scm.azurewebsites.net/azurejobs/#/functions, it shows all the logs, yet with many problem status "never finished" and end with status "failed", my guess is when it hit scheduled time, it will fire and keep trying to finish until failed

Comment: Any idea or direct here how I can increase the timeout for AzureStorage execution as mentioned in the snapshot? Since after I remove the time-consuming method, execution time less than 2mins, it will success, but I need that method, and now it at least takes 5mins, I bet it can allow that long, right? But I can not find a way to increase the timeout here, any information is appreciated!